# Can I define a method to accept EITHER a Func<T> OR an Expression<Func<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, overloading, func

If I attempt to write two overloads of a method, one accepting an `Expression<Func<T>>` parameter and another accepting a `Func<T>`, I will get a compiler error on trying to call the method with a lambda expression because the two signatures create ambiguity. The following would be problematic, for example:

```
Method(() => "Hello"); // Is that a Func<string>,
                       // or is it an Expression<Func<string>>?
```

I get that. But I don't like the approach of just accepting an `Expression<Func<string>>`, as this forces calling code to use a lambda expression. What if I want to be able to accept a method group as well?

My basis for asking this question is that I'm working on some code where I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
Method(() => "Hello");
```

...and get output like this:

```
Executed '() => "Hello"' and got "Hello" back.
```

Meanwhile, I'd like to be able to do this as well:

```
Method(ReturnHello);
```

...and get output like this:

```
Executed 'ReturnHello' and got "Hello" back.
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here, without just using two different method names (e.g., `ExpressionMethod` and `FuncMethod`)? I realize that wouldn't be such a big deal; I'm just curious if there's another way.

Comment: Why is the title using VB syntax and the rest of the question using C# syntax?

Comment: I think you'd have to use reflection to determine whether or not the passed delegate is a lambda expression or a function. But I think any code you write shouldn't change behaviour between the two; that seems like a nasty code smell to me.

Comment: @klausbyskov: I... don't know. I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload a method to take either a `Func<T>` or `Expression<Func<T>>` but when you do that the automatic type determination fails so you need to explicitly define the types via casting.  Like this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    Test((Func<string>)(() => "helllo"));
    Test((Expression<Func<string>>) (() => "hello"));
}

public static void Test<T>(Func<T> func)
{

}

public static void Test<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{

}
```

It's not pretty.

Comment: Gah, yeah... I just thought of that myself. You're *right*, but... I hate it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make one method with two named parameters with default values of null.

```
public static void Test<T>(Func<T> func = null, Expression<Func<T>> expression = null)
{
}
```

I know you miss the OR in this, but that's easy to check for in the method.

Comment: Whoa... haha, strange idea. Interesting, at least ;)