# Is there a way to have a function (overloaded or otherwise) accept either a Func or an Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

The question [Can I define a method to accept EITHER a Func OR an Expression<Func>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991363/can-i-define-a-method-to-accept-either-a-funct-or-an-expressionfunct) asks basically the same thing, but it was asked and answered in 2010 and C# has changed quite a bit since then.

I have a filter method, `SelectItems`, that accepts a `Func<Thing, bool>`, where `Thing` is an individual item in a collection and the `bool` return value is whether or not the item passes the filter.

`SelectItems` is used in multiple places in the codebase.  Some places pass expression lambdas and others pass statement lambdas.

If no items in the collection pass the filter, it throws an exception with an exception message that describes the collection.  Because this code is referenced in many places, I would like to add a description of the filter itself to the exception message - something like `Item matching filter "(item) => item % 2 == 0" was not found.  Items found: 1, 3, 5, 7`.

If the filter function accepts an `Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>`, I can print the function itself with a `PrettyPrintCSharpCode` method.  There are probably other ways to pull information from an `Expression`, but pretty printing the code would suffice for now.  If a `Func` is passed, though, the message will not be able to include the code.  This is fine, and probably the biggest difference between the question I linked above and mine.

If all calls to this function only passed expression lambdas, I could simply change the function argument to an `Expression` and it would work implicitly.  The problem I've run into is that many of the calls pass statement lambdas, so those calls break.

What I would like is to be able to pass either an expression lambda or a statement lambda.

I tried overloading the function (with one overload accepting Func and the other an Expression), but the compiler is unable to properly pass the expression lambdas to the function that accepts an `Expression` and the statement lambdas to the function that excepts a `Func`.

I also tried optional arguments (something like `SelectItems(Func<Thing, bool> func = null, Expression<Func<Thing, bool>> expr = null)`) but it had the same issue.

If I overloaded a function to accept an `int` or a `double`, the compiler would figure out the best fit.  I'm confused that it doesn't do that for this.

Specifically, the code

```cs
class ClassName
    void SelectItems(Expression<Func<Thing, bool>> filterExpression) {}

    void SelectItems(Func<Thing, bool> filterFunc) {}
```

generates this compiler error

```cs
void ClassName.SelectItems(Func<Thing, bool> filterFunc) (+ 1 overload)

CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
    'ClassName.SelectItems(Func<Thing, bool>)' and 
    'ClassName.SelectItems(Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>)'

Ambiguous invocation:
    void SelectItems(System.Func<Thing, bool>) (in class ClassName)
    void SelectItems(System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<Thing, bool>>) (in class ClassName)
match
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly provide parameter name:

```cs
SelectItems(filterFunc: t => true); // uses Func overload
SelectItems(filterExpression: t => true); // uses Expression overload
```

Though it is a bit brittle.

Another way is to explicitly specify the type:

```cs
SelectItems((Func<Thing, bool>)(t => true))
SelectItems((Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>)(t => true))
```

Compiler can disambiguate between the two, problem is that compiler infers the type for lambda expressions like `t => true` from the context and both `Func<T, bool>` and `Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>` are valid in the provided case hence the ambiguity.

From the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1120-expression):

> The result of an expression is classified as one of the following:
>
> - ...
> - An anonymous function. An expression with this classification can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type.
> - ...

and

> The evaluation of an anonymous-function conversion depends on **the target type** of the conversion: If it is a delegate type, the conversion evaluates to a delegate value referencing the method that the anonymous function defines. If it is an expression-tree type, the conversion evaluates to an expression tree that represents the structure of the method as an object structure.

Comment: The frustrating thing is that if I have `void Foo(int bar)` and `void Foo(double bar)`, then `Foo(5)` calls the first and `Foo(5.5)` calls the second.

I suppose that if I have `void Foo(float bar)` instead of `void Foo(int bar)`, then `Foo(5)` would fail because they're both equally valid conversions, which is actually closer to my current situation.

Comment: That does make me realize that `void SelectItems(Func<GridRow, bool> filterFunc = null, Expression<Func<GridRow, bool>> filterExpression = null)` will accept any lambda expression, cast it to a `Func`, and pass that to `filterFunc`... but you can explicitly pass it to the `filterExpression` with `SelectItems(filterExpression: t => t % 2 == 0)`.  Still doesn't really do what I want, which is to implicitly (without any changes anywhere but the function itself) convert it to an `Expression` but it is the next best thing.

Comment: @Blarghedy _"will accept any lambda expression, cast it to a Func, and pass that to filterFunc"_ - no, there is no implicit conversion between `Expression<Func<...>>` and corresponding `Func<...>`.

Comment: @Blarghedy that's the rules. This is caused basically by the same principle as why you can't write `var func = t => true;`. _"Foo(5) would fail"_ - actually no, the `float` overload will be used (not sure why though, maybe conversion to float is "better").

Comment: Yeah, you're correct - it uses float.  The precedence is interesting.  It seems to be `nint`, `long`, `float`, and `double` or `decimal` (equal precedence).  I assume it prefers `float` because it's the smallest floating number that can accurately store an integer.